# Como desenvolver para Windows Phone 8 usando Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

Queria saber como posso desenvolver para windows phone 8 usando VS2013, porque só tem a opção para Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é irrelevante hoje.

A [recomendação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/br211384(v=win.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é usar o VS 2012 se realmente precisa disto. Mas ela fala em instalar o SDK do 8 opcionalmente no VS 2013. De fato [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18099625/221800) no SO mostra isto.

Pense bem se realmente quer fazer isso. Esta versão é considerada obsoleta e tende a desaparecer logo, principalmente porque muito pouco vendido.

Answer (score 1):

Eu encontrei como fazer um app para Windows Phone 8 usando o Visual Studio 2013.

Na Hora da criação do projeto é só escolher Blank App(Windows Phone Silverlight). Assim a pessoa tem a opção do desenvolvimento para WP8.

[image: Escolha do Tipo de Projeto]

[image: WP8]